# How to access ping't time

Tags: network-programming, ping

when in win7 I ping some ip the result like this
" Reply from 113.164.49.22: bytes=32 time=256ms TTL=47" Is there any command to change output to just time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ping /?` gives help. It doesn't show an option that will display only the time.

It shouldn't be difficult to cobble up a Powershell script that uses a regular expression to strip out just the time portion.

Comment: I am familiar with awk Do you know awk script for that? The problem is time is near = sign there is no space

Comment: It's been years since I worked with awk. I think the regex you want would be something like `/\stime=\d+ms/`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/340583/how-to-write-an-awk-script-that-catch-pings-time/340595?noredirect=1#340595

Comment: This does a full capture: /time=\d+/g     .... if you want just the time then: /(?<=time=)\d+/g

Comment: Link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/340583/how-to-write-an-awk-script-that-catch-pings-time